# To find $k$ such that slanted line gets mapped to vertical line

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Given, $T:R^2\to R^2$, a horizontal shear, whose standard matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & k \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. It is asked to find $k$ if possible, so that line **x**=$\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -3 \end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}1  \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$, gets mapped into a vertical line.

I think it is impossible to find such $k$. Because, horizontal shear will just shift the given line without changing it's slope, i.e. we will have some parallel line to the original one, so suck $k$ does not exist. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the matrix on to the line: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&k\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2+t\\-3+4t\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}(2-3k)+(1+4k)t\\-3+4t\end{bmatrix}$$ This is a line passing through $(2-3k,-3)$ with direction $(1+4k,4)$. So to get a vertical line, choose $k=-1/4$.

Comment: wow.. actually I thought that every vector will receive same translation under shear so resultant line will be parallel, thanks